# Xdebug with Docker on Windows and PhpStorm

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I run a Docker image with Symfony and API-platform. My docker image is running on Windows with Traefik.

When I start Xdebug (In PhpStorm and Chrome), it stops in the `public/index.php` if I put a breakpoint, but when I put a breakpoint in a controller or in an Authenticator, there is no break. When I add a debug line with `dd()`, I can debug but the purpose is doing this with Xdebug.

What can I look to understand what's wrong ?

OS: Windows 10
IDE: PhpStorm
PHP: Symfony 5 / Api Platform / PHP 7.4

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem, In "Language & Frameworks > PHP > Servers" the absolute path in my docker image was set only for the public folder. i updated the absolute path for the parent folder "src > /var/www/html" and now it works